# Keep Component Inspector state between applications switch in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, inspector

On `NetBeans` 7.0.1, if you are designing two User Interfaces, the "`Component Inspector`" becomes available while at "`Design View`", if you switch from one UI to another the Inspector  randomly collapses all nodes and you lose focus of the component you had previously selected.

This is annoying because you have to keep expanding the nodes to get focus on what you were working.

One solution is to have multiple `NetBeans` instances, this may work if you must have two UI opened at the same time, but what if you must have five UIs opened at the same time? 5 NetBeans instances is not an option.

So, do you know what do I have to do so the `Component Inspector` does not collapse when switching between files? or in another words, how to keep the component inspector state between applications switch?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this as an answer to show screenshots)

I do not get the same behavior as you do. In my case the Inspector does not collapse the panels when switching between open files, only when closing & opening a file. My IDE looks like the screenshots below when switching between the file tabs (CheckPanel.java & PasswordEditPanel.java).

So the functionality is definitely there, but something is amiss in your case.

[image: CheckPanel.java]

[image: PasswordEditPanel.java]